# ¿Por qué no puedo definir las dimensiones de un arreglo bidimensional con variables int? C

Tags: array, c, array-bidimensional, indices

**Tengo el siguiente código en C**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int row=2, col=3, f,c;
   char array[row][col] = { {'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'a', 'b', 'c'} };

   for(f=0; f<row; f++) {
      for(c=0; c<col; c++)
         printf("%c", a[f][c]);
      printf("\n");

   }

   return 0;
}
```

**¿Por qué esta línea NO funciona así?:**
`char array[row][col] = { {'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'a', 'b', 'c'} };`

> error: excess elements in array initializer

**Pero, ¿Por qué SÍ funciona así?:**
`char array[2][3] = { {'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'a', 'b', 'c'} };`

> Errores(0)
> Advertencias(0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C y C++ el tamaño de los arreglos debe conocerse en tiempo de compilación. Por eso no puedes usar variables para declararlos.

Lo que si puedes hacer es definir el arreglo y dejar que el compilador infiera el tamaño.

Así:

```
int arreglo[][] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
```

O si necesitas que el tamaño sea dinámico, deberás usar el heap.

```
int n = 2, m = 3;
// Reservas memoria
int *arreglo = (int*)malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
// Puedes "mapear" el arreglo como bidimensional mediante algunos cálculos
int pos1 = 1, pos = 2;
int elemento = arreglo[pos1 * m + pos2];
// Liberas la memoria cuando no la usas más
free(arreglo);
```

Comment: ¿Qué clase de expresión es esta?: ```int elemento = arreglo[pos1 * 3 + pos2]``` ¿En qué consiste?

Comment: Guardar en la variable `elemento` el elemento de `arreglo` en la posición `pos1 * m + 2` . Con el cálculo indicado, puedes convertir un par ordenado o "las coordenadas" de un arreglo bidimensional a uno unidimensional.